# Making custom Tabbar using CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to make a custom tabbar menu using CollectionView for the header menu and ScrollView for the screens.
My problem here is I want the indicator to move along when I scroll the ScrollView, stop at the right tab position and resized according to the tab's size, like the one in youtube app in the image below. How can I achieve this ?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: This project has a horizontal slide-bar: https://github.com/eonist/FlowLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. I managed to achieve it with the following code:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet private var myTabBarView: MyTabBarView?
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        myTabBarView?.progress = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.width
    }
    
}

class MyTabBarView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet private var myTabPanels: [UIView] = [] // A list of your views to which the indicator should snap
    @IBOutlet private var indicatorCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? // indicatorView.centerX = superview.leading
    @IBOutlet private var indicatorWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            refresh()
        }
    }
    
    private func refresh() {
        guard myTabPanels.count > 0 else { return }
        
        let position: (width: CGFloat, xOffset: CGFloat) = {
            guard myTabPanels.count > 1 else {
                return (myTabPanels[0].frame.width, myTabPanels[0].frame.midX)
            }
            
            let upperBound = CGFloat(myTabPanels.count-1)
            
            guard progress < upperBound else {
                return (myTabPanels.last!.frame.width, myTabPanels.last!.frame.midX)
            }
            
            let actualProgress = max(0.0, min(progress, upperBound))
            let startIndex = Int(actualProgress) // Index of view on the left
            let progressToNextView = actualProgress - CGFloat(startIndex) // Progress between view on the  left and view on the right
            
            let widths: (left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) = (myTabPanels[startIndex].frame.width, myTabPanels[startIndex+1].frame.width)
            let xOffsets: (left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) = (myTabPanels[startIndex].frame.midX, myTabPanels[startIndex+1].frame.midX)
            
            func interpolate(values: (from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat), scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
                values.from + (values.to - values.from)*scale
            }
            
            return (interpolate(values: (widths.left, widths.right), scale: progressToNextView), interpolate(values: (xOffsets.left, xOffsets.right), scale: progressToNextView))
        }()
        
        indicatorCenterXConstraint?.constant = position.xOffset
        indicatorWidthConstraint?.constant = position.width
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

In storyboard I added a scroll view with horizontal stack view to simulate multiple screens as you described. The scroll view has a delegate set to a view controller which then implements `scrollViewDidScroll` to update the indicator position depending on the scroll. The progress is sent to tab bar view as floating index of screen that is shown.

Tab bar view is also in same storyboard. I added same number of views in tab bar as there are screens in scroll view. (In my case I simply used text labels which have different size depending on their text). The 3 views (labels) are connected to `myTabPanels` in same order as representing screens in scroll view.

Next to that I added a normal `UIView` representing my indicator. I used constraints as described in the comments; Indicator center X equals to leading of its superview. Indicator has fixed width. And I connected the two constraints to `indicatorCenterXConstraint` and `indicatorWidthConstraint`. (I also set vertical constraint, fixed height and some background color).

Now as I scroll a new progress is computed and passed to tab bar view. A `refresh` method is called which computes new positions and updates the indicator correctly. All seems to work fine. So to break down the code:

When there is only 1 view there should be no computation. Indicator is fixed on it

```
guard myTabPanels.count > 1 else {
    return (myTabPanels[0].frame.width, myTabPanels[0].frame.midX)
}
```

When user scrolled past the last view then keep on the last item. Indicator can not go further.

```
let upperBound = CGFloat(myTabPanels.count-1)

guard progress < upperBound else {
    return (myTabPanels.last!.frame.width, myTabPanels.last!.frame.midX)
}
```

Only allow progress between `0.0` and `upperBound`. These are basically minimum and maximum indices possible.

```
let actualProgress = max(0.0, min(progress, upperBound))
```

Start index and progress view break down for instance value `3.25` to `3` and `0.25`. Meaning that we are 25% past the screen with index 3.

```
let startIndex = Int(actualProgress) // Index of view on the left
let progressToNextView = actualProgress - CGFloat(startIndex) // Progress between view on the  left and view on the right
```

If we are between index 3 and 4 then we are interested what are positions of views that represent screen with index 3 and 4. These are stored under `left` and `right`.

```
let widths: (left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) = (myTabPanels[startIndex].frame.width, myTabPanels[startIndex+1].frame.width)
let xOffsets: (left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) = (myTabPanels[startIndex].frame.midX, myTabPanels[startIndex+1].frame.midX)
```

A standard linear interpolation

```
func interpolate(values: (from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat), scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    values.from + (values.to - values.from)*scale
}
```

Simply return interpolated values

```
return (interpolate(values: (widths.left, widths.right), scale: progressToNextView), interpolate(values: (xOffsets.left, xOffsets.right), scale: progressToNextView))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Matic, but can you explain the indicator constraint part ? Where do you put it so that you have the constraint centerX = superview.leading ? What view is the superview ? In my case I just put the indicator view right at the bottom of the CollectionView.

And the panels are labels with dynamic width, so the header menu needs to be scrollable (CollectionView in my case), did you test when you scroll the header, the indicator stay on the panel that is selected ?

Comment: @minhquynguyen So your tab bar is already a collection view? That may not be the best idea in your case. We could still programmatically add a view and constrain it to selected cell. It would work because collection view is a subclass of scrollview. It is just that you can not add it in storyboard. But the thing is that collection view is designed to recycle cells. So when user would scroll and indicator would not yet be visible then also the cell would be removed or reused and moved to another position. At that point indicator would either break completely or be in a wrong position.

Comment: @minhquynguyen There are still other ways of doing it with collection view. You would need to be able to compute frames instead of having them automatic. You could then always compute where the indicator should be, even if it is off the screen. But possibly there is much easier way; instead of collection view simply use a scroll view with horizontal stack view.

Comment: Thank you, I will take your advice and try it with horizontal stack view instead. And one last thing, I'm still confused about the constraint "indicatorView.centerX = superview.leading". Where do you put your indicator to have that constraint ? What view is the superview ?

Comment: @minhquynguyen the superview is considered to be the view on which you add indicator view. Generally it should be the same view that is a superview of all your tab bar views. When that is not the case then you need to convert frames whenever used as in `indicatorView.superview!.convert(tabBarView.bounds, from: tabBarView)`